# Cobalt raspi-2_gold is unable to play video

Tags: audio, video, raspbian, cobalt

When running raspi-2_gold of cobalt, it is unable to play the selected video. It is stuck at the black screen.

What works:

1. It is able to load all the thumbnails initially
2. Able to select a video
3. All video controls working fine
4. Did try nerd stats, **NO** frames received, displaying Codecs, ID, viewport, Volume, Connection speed, Buffer health.
5. also all thumbnails below the video are shown

What doesn't:

1. No video as well as audio
2. Tried videos of all resolution, results are same = NO Video & Audio

Questions:

1. Are there specific certificate requirements
2. Any audio/video library requirements

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
[2278:1362215416:ERROR:player_internal.cc(134)] Not implemented reached in void SbPlayerPrivate::SetVolume(double)
[2280:1362347860:WARNING:thread_set_name.cc(36)] Thread name "omx_video_decoder" was truncated to "omx_video_decod"
[2279:1362349124:INFO:player_worker.cc(136)] Try to seek to timestamp 0
[2280:1362352181:INFO:open_max_component_base.cc(82)] Opened "OMX.broadcom.video_decode" with port 130 and 131
[2283:1363620269:INFO:alsa_audio_sink_type.cc(241)] alsa::AlsaAudioSink enters idle loop
[2282:1363554339:FATAL:open_max_component.cc(216)] Check failed: false. OMX_EventError received with 80001000 0
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponent::OnErrorEvent() [0x17eedd8]
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponentBase::OnEvent() [0x17f34ec]
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponentBase::EventHandler() [0x17f375c]

Caught signal: SIGABRT (6)
    <unknown> [0x75cc6180]
    <unknown> [0x75cc4f70]
Aborted
```

Comment: Hi there, yes video playback on the Raspberry Pi should work.  I assume you followed the instructions at https://cobalt.foo/development/setup-raspi.html ?  Do you know what model of Raspberry Pi you are using?  Do you know what version of Raspbian you are using?  If you build Cobalt in Devel or QA, does it work?  You will see more log output in a Devel or QA build, if video playback does not work in those builds, there will likely be more information in stdout/stderr logs on those builds.

Comment: @Andrew Top i'm using Raspberry pi 2 with raspbian Jessie. I haven't tried devel and qa builds but i have seen the debug build. The debug build crashes with some error involving openMax class at similar stage.

Comment: Aha!  The debug build (or the devel build, which runs a bit faster) shouldn't be crashing (it does not crash for me).  Since the crash involves openMAX, it is very likely that the crash in debug is the same reason why you see no video in gold (which omits the debug assertions that are likely being set off).  Can you provide more information about those crashes?

Comment: @AndrewTop thanks for looking into this. I have added the last part of the log that is generated. To my understanding, this is where the error is pointed out.

Comment: It looks like the error code 80001000 is associated with the message "There were insufficient resources to perform the requested operation".  Perhaps your Raspberry Pi's memory split is misconfigured?  When you type "sudo raspi-config", and go to "Advanced", what do you see for "Memory Split"?  Can you try setting it to 512MB?

Comment: @AndrewTop thank you for the suggestion it worked. It even worked on 256 MB. Kindly post this as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `@Andrew Top` for the answer. Setting the memory split to 256 MB worked. Videos were playing quite well. The HQ videos and 360 degree ones need up to 256 MB of GPU, 720p and below could be played in at least 200 Mb of GPU.